# Take out parameter from url

Tags: java, url, getparameter

I have a very long url with numbers of parameter like

```
http://localhost:8080/BUUK/dbcc?dssin=9371062001&roundid=JS&KIPL=02&PLATFORM=1&FREQUENCY=2&DRBEARER=1&BUYTYPE=1&EUP=12&TID=72123456435653654&SHORTCODE=54300&ADCODE=234rfdfsf&Buytag=3&Checkpoint=5,6,7&CHARGEMODEL=complete&restbalance=1
```

I want retrieve all the parameter from this url.

I was wondering if i can use `request.getParamter("restbalance");`

I will provide more info if required.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to retrieve parameters inside the servlet ?

Comment: @AzAh yes you can.Did you try before posting this question? Or is there something else you want to make a not of?

Comment: @captain I tried, damn I was not using it correctly.
NOW I am using it with the beans and a method with `HttpServletRequest` parameter which sets all the bean.
All the answer was helpful. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each request your web server more precisely your web container creates a two object  request and response.

**HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse**

The servletcontainer is attached to a webserver which listens on HTTP requests on a certain port number, which is usually 80. When a client (user with a webbrowser) sends a HTTP request, the servletcontainer will create new HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects and pass it through the methods of the already-created Filter and Servlet instances whose url-pattern matches the request URL, all in the same thread.

**The request object provides access to all information of the HTTP request, such as the request headers and the request body**. The response object provides facility to control and send the HTTP response the way you want, such as setting headers and the body (usually with HTML content from a JSP file). When the HTTP response is committed and finished, then both the request and response objects will be trashed.

`request.getParameter("request_param");` will give you `request_param` value.
So there is nothing to get surprise accessing `request parameter` from `request object`

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with `HttpServletRequest` you can use

```
String restbalance = request.getParameter("restbalance");
```

or...to get all the parameteres, you can do:

```
String[] params = request.getParameterValues();
```

Here's the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) for the `HttpServletRequest` class, with all the available methods listed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use request.getParameter where request is the object of HttpServletRequest.

From the javadocs
[getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

> java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name) Returns the value
>   of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not
>   exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the request.
>   For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or
>   posted form data. You should only use this method when you are sure
>   the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more
>   than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).
>
> If you use this method with a multivalued parameter, the value
>   returned is equal to the first value in the array returned by
>   getParameterValues.
>
> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs
>   with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of this method.

Comment: `request` can be an object of any `ServletRequest` not necessarily `HttpServletRequest` . See it is declared in `ServletRequest` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getParameterMap()`

```
Map params = request.getParameterMap();
Iterator i = params.keySet().iterator();
while ( i.hasNext() )

{

String key = (String) i.next();

String value = ((String[]) params.get( key ))[ 0 ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , `request.getparameter()` will work fine only if the `request` hits your *Servlet* from where you want to get hold of the request parameters . Please go through the documentation [ServletRequest](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) interface for all the relevant methods for your purpose.

1. `getParameter();`
2. `getParameterNames();`
3. `getParameterValues();`
4. `getParameterMap();`

You can also use [HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) for custom parsing.

For normal Java code , you can parse the string returned by [URL.getQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getQuery%28%29) yourself to extract the data .